# Error ssl instagram api cURL error 35: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading

Tags: php, laravel, instagram

When I make request to Instagram API I get response like this:

> cURL error 35: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

I use MacOS and sail as local server.

```
$response = Http::withOptions([
        "verify"=>false,
        'version' =>  3.1

    ])->post($this->accessTokenUrl, [
        'code' => $code,
        'client_id' => $this->clientId,
        'client_secret' => $this->secret,
        'grant_type' => self::GRANT_TYPE,
        'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUrl,
    ]);
```

I tried to make a request using vanilla PHP methods, but it didn't give results.

Comment: Something is closing the connection from the remote side.